# Custom Route Not Found in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created this route:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Pages", _
        "Pages/{id}/{title}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Pages", .id = UrlParameter.Optional, .title = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

I then created the following "Pages" action in my "Home" controller:

```
Function Pages(Optional ByVal id = 0, Optional ByVal title = "") As ActionResult

    Dim db As NavDbContext = New NavDbContext
    Dim page = db.Tbl_Navigations.Where(Function(p) p.NAV_ID = id)

    If (page.Any) Then

        Dim _title = page.Single.NAV_Element.ToString
        Dim content = page.Single.NAV_Content.ToString
        ViewBag.Title = _title
        ViewBag.Content = content

    End If

    Return View()

End Function
```

When I navigate to ~/Pages/8/MyPage (which is a valid ID in my database), it says, "The resource cannot be found."  How can I route this properly?  Thanks.

Comment: Is your controller method executing?  If it is, it's not a problem with your routes.  If it isn't, use Phil Haack's Route Debugger to find out which route your request is actually hitting.

Comment: Have you installed the routedebugger? 
is your action being executed? 
is this the only route in your route table? 
where is this particular route placed in conjunction with the other routes that you might possibly have?

Comment: I will try Phil Haack's Route Debugger tomorrow and let you know.  This is the only route I have created other than the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` that comes with MVC.  The custom route is placed beneath the default route in the RegisterRoutes method of the `Global.asax` file.

Comment: Routes are matching in definition order. Try to put the your `"Pages"` route first then the `default {controller}/{action}/{id}` route.

Comment: @nemesv:  Thanks, your comment seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tommy:  Correction:  This is VB.Net :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have more than one `UrlParameter.Optional` in your route and the optional parameter must be the last parameter in the route.  Remove the `UrlParameter.Optional` from the id portion of your route.

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "Pages", _
        "Pages/{id}/{title}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Pages", .title = UrlParameter.Optional})
```

And the Controller Action Method

```
Function Pages(ByVal id As Integer, Optional ByVal title = "") As ActionResult
```

If both parameters are required for this route, then you do not need to specify any of the parameters as optional to ensure that that particular route handles **only** the request that it should.

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "Pages", _
        "Pages/{id}/{title}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Pages"})
```

And the Controller Action Method

```
Function Pages(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal title As String) As ActionResult
```

Comment: And make sure your Pages route comes before the default MVC one, `/Pages/8/MyPage` will be matched first by `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Comment: I didn't do anything except change the order of the Routes in global.aspx, putting the custom route first.  That seems to make it work.  Thanks to you both.